# Return string without trailing '/' character

Tags: string, url, powershell

I am having trouble in PowerShell error checking a variable for a trailing slash and removing it. For example:

```
$example1 = 'https://mysite.com/siteone'
$example2 = 'https://mysite.com/sitetwo/'
```

How do I check for a trailing slash? So if my script returns `$example1`, that's fine and script continues.  However, if it returns `$example2` it removes the trailing slash and makes it just:

```
https://mysite.com/sitetwo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just trim any trailing `/` characters with [`String.TrimEnd`](http://ss64.com/ps/trim.html):

```
PS > $example1 = 'https://mysite.com/siteone'
PS > $example1.TrimEnd('/')
https://mysite.com/siteone
PS > $example2 = 'https://mysite.com/sitetwo/'
PS > $example2.TrimEnd('/')
https://mysite.com/sitetwo
PS >
```